# How can I load bitmaps into my Flash game to use as reusable blocks?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I'm making a basic platformer game in Adobe Flash using Actionscript 3, based on the tutorial found [here](http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-platform-game-in-as3-part-1/). This tutorial uses basic graphics drawing for the various elements of the game, using different shapes and colors. Can anyone show what extra code would be necessary to have the game elements be drawn from various bitmap images? For example, to have a basic pixel pattern tile over for the blocks you stand on. I'm new to actionscript, and this seems fairly complicated. Any help is appreciated!

Basically, this game creates it's blocks using code, not elements on the stage. I was hoping someone could tell me what additional code I could add so that I can create these elements from bitmaps.

PS: The completed source code from the tutorial can found [here](http://www.flashgametuts.com/obj/tuts/platform-as3/pt7/platform-as3-source.zip).

Comment: This isn't an Actionscript thing as much as a "how do I put elements on the stage?"  Look up how movie clips and the timeline work.  That will steer you the right way.

Comment: Use `graphics.beginBitmapFill()` in conjunction with layered sprites. So far the question is too broad.

Comment: I know it's broad, but that's only because I know very little about Actionscript so far.